# Is there a way to code the Fibonacci Sequence to only get one output

Tags: python, python-3.x

Many of the questions and answers I’ve seen on here give an answer of multiple outputs however I want only one single answer can anyone help? For example with this code when you choose a number in this case ‘9’ you get ‘0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21’ what I want is if I say ‘9’ I just get an answer of ‘21’ nothing before it.

```
nterms = int(input("How many terms? "))

n1, n2 = 0, 1
count = 0

if nterms <= 0:
   print("Please enter a positive integer")
elif nterms == 1:
   print("Fibonacci sequence upto",nterms,":")
   print(n1)
else:
   print("Fibonacci sequence:")
   while count < nterms:
       print(n1)
       nth = n1 + n2
       n1 = n2
       n2 = nth
       count += 1
```

Comment: Just take out the `print` statement in the loop, and do one `print` at the end.

Comment: I tried that already and when I do it messes up the values. It makes 1 equal to 0 so it’s always one off. If I were to type ‘9’ the output would be ‘34’

Comment: Stop the loop one iteration sooner, then.  `while count < nterms - 1`.

Comment: Thank you that solved it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to recursively calculate the `n` number of the sequence:

```
def fibMem(n, mem={}):
    if n in mem:
        return mem[n]
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    mem[n] = fibMem(n-1, mem) + fibMem(n-2, mem)
    return mem[n]
num = 9
print(fibMem(num-2))
```

Comment: This does not produce the right number, fibMem(9) returns 55 and not 21 ?

Comment: @GeirVilly You're right, I have already solved it

Comment: Well, now it produce 34 @Cardstdani, which still is not 21 ?

Comment: @GeirVilly Solved

Comment: I like the compactness of you code, so I will allow myself to fix it: replacing `return mem[n]` with `return mem[n] -1` allows you to call `fibMem(num)' instead of `num - 2`... that is, in your original code you get the the fibo value of 9 by giving 7 to the funciton, not 9. Fixed now.

Comment: @GeirVilly Well, I think that modifying the input to the function is more simple than modifying the function itself, but it would work anyways.

Comment: that worries me. If you some day get involved in a bigger software development project, I think you will quickly change you mind about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of lenght ‚nterms‘ and get the last element of it with array.pop. Or you can assign the current value of fibonaci to a variable and as the loop finishes print the last assigned value.

```
def fibo():
    while count < nterms:
        f = a + b
        a = b
        b = f
        count += 1
    print(f)
```

Comment: Please provide some code too as a solution

Answer (score 0):

```
nterms = int(input("How many terms? "))

n1, n2 = 0, 1
count = 0

if nterms <= 0:
   print("Please enter a positive integer")
elif nterms == 1:
   print("Fibonacci sequence upto",nterms,":")
   print(n1)
else:
   print("Fibonacci sequence:")
   while count < nterms:
       if count + 1 >= nterms:
           print(n1)

       nth = n1 + n2
       n1 = n2
       n2 = nth
       count += 1
```

Comment: [Python tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/index.htm) will definitely help you understand code.

Comment: [edit]ing is also possible btw

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
nterms = int(input("How many terms? "))

n1, n2 = 0, 1
count = 0

if nterms <= 0:
   print("Please enter a positive integer")
elif nterms == 1:
   print("Fibonacci sequence upto",nterms,":")
   print(n1)
else:
   print("Fibonacci sequence:")
   while count < (nterms-1):
       nth = n1 + n2
       n1 = n2
       n2 = nth
       count += 1  
print(n1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on you original code, I suggest just making a function that print only the final number:

```py
def final_fib(nterms, print_all=False):
    n1, n2, count = 0, 1, 0

    if nterms <= 0:
       print("Please enter a positive integer")
       return 
    elif nterms == 1:
       print("Fibonacci sequence upto",nterms,":")
       return(n1)
    
    fib_nrs = list()
    fib_nrs.append(n1)
    
    while count < nterms:
        if print_all:
            print(n1)
        fib_nrs.append(n1)
        nth = n1 + n2
        n1 = n2
        n2 = nth
        count += 1
    if not print_all:
        print(fib_nrs[-1])
```

Which would give:

```py
final_fib(9)
21
```

Note, that I also made it possible to print all numbers by setting `print_all=False`. That is;

```py
final_fib(9, print_all=True)
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
```